# Defining analyzer while querying in elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am pretty new to elasticsearch and just need some clarification:
Can we define a analyzer while querying the search server. I tried it with the "text" and "field" query and it works fine:

Query:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test/user/_search? -d '{ "query" : {
"text" : {"_all" : {"query" :"Vaibhav","analyzer" :
"lowercase_keyword" }} } }'
```

Result:

```
{"took":144,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":0.10848885,"hits":{"_index":"test","_type":"user","_id":"1","_score":0.10848885,
"_source" : {
   "first_name": "Vaibhav",
   "last_name":"saini",
   "password":"pwd"
```

But when I try to do the same thing with term/prefix/wildcard query I get the exception:

Query:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test/user/_search? -d '{
"query" : { "term" : {"_all" : {"query" :"Vaibhav","analyzer" :
"lowercase_keyword" }} } }'
```

Result:

```
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures
{[kws9J6tbQtWCMNKBm3Gpkw][test][4]: SearchParseException[[test][4]:
from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
[\n{\n\"query\" : {\n\"term\" : {\"_all\" : {\"query\"
:\"Vaibhav\",\"analyzer\" : \"lowercase_keyword\" }}\n}\n}]]]; nested:
QueryParsingException[[test] [term] query does not support [query]];
}{[kws9J6tbQtWCMNKBm3Gpkw][test][1]: SearchParseException[[test][1]:
from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
[\n{\n\"query\" : {\n\"term\" : {\"_all\" : {\"query\"
:\"Vaibhav\",\"analyzer\" : \"lowercase_keyword\" }}\n}\n}]]]; nested:
QueryParsingException[[test] [term] query does not support [query]];
}{[kws9J6tbQtWCMNKBm3Gpkw][test][2]: SearchParseException[[test][2]:
from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
[\n{\n\"query\" : {\n\"term\" : {\"_all\" : {\"query\"
:\"Vaibhav\",\"analyzer\" : \"lowercase_keyword\" }}\n}\n}]]]; nested:
QueryParsingException[[test] [term] query does not support [query]];
}]","status":500}
```

So is it like we can't define analayzers while querying the elasticsearch server for some type of queries and for others we can? If not, am I doing anything wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `term`, `prefix`, and `wildcard` queries expect the value specified in the query to be already analyzed.

Comment: The elasticsearch document says that term query Matches documents that have fields that contain a term (not analyzed). http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query.html

Comment: Thanks Imotov. But i have a doubt here, if this is the case, then in the example above while querying i should get the result regardless of what casing i am using.For ex: in my index data in "first_name" field is "Vaibhav",also the analyzer used for this field is custom analyzer which uses tokenizer as "Keyword" and filter as "lowercase", so that my data is indexed as "vaibhav" instead of "Vaibhav" which is as expected.

Comment: Now when i query it using a term/prefix/wildcard query on "vaibhav" i get the result,but when i query it on "Vaibhav" i don't get the result(maybe because it is indexed as "vaibhav"). So my requirement here is that my query should be case insensitive. thanks

Comment: When you are using "text" and "field" queries, analyzers are applied during both indexing and searching. For term/prefix/wildcard queries analyzers are not applied during searching. You correctly stated that "Vaibhav" is indexed as the term "vaibhav". That's why when you are searching for the term "vaibhav" you are getting results, but when you are searching for the term "Vaibhav" you are not getting any results - the term "Vaibhav" simply doesn't exist in the index. If you want your query to be case insensitive (analyzed), you need to use "text" or "field" queries instead of "term" queries.

Comment: But for `query`, how to embed the `analyzer` while querying?

Answer (score 10):

This syntax worked for me:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "controller": {
        "analyzer": "keyword",
        "query": "api/v2/test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Find more details in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-match-query.html#_phrase).

Comment: although this JSON not work for me, but analyzer required is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom [search-analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) to be used for queries.

From the docs:

> Usually, the same analyzer should be applied at index time and at
>   search time, to ensure that the terms in the query are in the same format as
>   the terms in the inverted index.
>
> Sometimes, though, it can make sense to use a different analyzer at search
>   time, such as when using the analysis-edgengram-tokenizer for autocomplete.
>
> By default, queries will use the `analyzer` defined in the field mapping, but
>   this can be overridden with the `search_analyzer` setting

The docs also list an example. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html